# ImportError: No module named os when Running .exe file py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, py2exe

I've created an `.exe` of my python file. When I run the `.exe` file I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:---\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\boot_common.py", line
> 92, in
>
> import linecache
>
> ImportError: No module named linecache
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mypythonfile.py", line 8, in
>
> ImportError: No module named os'

Comment: did you run the .exe with all the other stuff it comes with? or did you copy the executable somewhere else before running it ?

Comment: No I did not move it.

Comment: can you post your `setup.py` file along with a minimal script just importing the modules you're importing (not the full code) so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: Title is more clear about the question.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `. exe` file and just run (`x` is package)

```
pip install x
pip install module
```

Then create again the executable file with `pyinstaller`.
It worked for me.